# Date Format Java?

Tags: java, date

I have 3 int variables for Month, Day and Year.

How can I convert them to a `java.util.Date` object (or whatever).

For Example, Month = 12, Date = 20, Year = 2011

It should be print in medium date format: `**Dec 20, 2011**`

Thank you very much!

Edit here my try:

```
String yourBirthDay = Integer.toString(birthMonth) + "." + Integer.toString(birthDay) + "." + Integer.toString(birthYear);
        DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);

        try {
            Date date = format.parse(yourBirthDay);
            System.out.println("Your birth date is : " + date.toString());

        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: could not parse date in string \""
                    + yourBirthDay + "\"");
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did this little test using [Calendar.set(int year,int month, int date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29):

```
@Test
public void testDate() throws ParseException {

    int year = 2011, month = 12, date = 20;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(year, month - 1, date);

    Date javaDate = calendar.getTime();

    // SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");

    DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);

    String stringDate = format.format(javaDate);

    assertEquals("Dec 20, 2011", stringDate);

}
```

You need to remove 1 from the month because java.util.Calendar works with zero based months.

Comment: `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT)` will return `12/20/11` instead of `Dec 20, 2011`, is that OK?

Comment: Edited, just use `DateFormat.MEDIUM`

Comment: Excellent. I appreciated it. Happy Holiday or whatever day to you!